# How to cache a PHP generated XML file in Drupal?

Tags: php, xml, drupal, caching, drupal-6

I'm using [ammap](http://www.ammap.com/) to display a map. On click, the user gets a list of latest Drupal 6 nodes tagged with the respective country (taxonomy). The list is generated by a view. To accomplish that, I use the basic ammap XML code, but I added some PHP to include the view, i.e.:

```php
<?php
//set the working directory
chdir('..');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

//Load Drupal
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 

header ("Content-Type:text/xml");

?>

<map map_file="maps/world3.swf" tl_long="-117.2" tl_lat="33.3" br_long="-94.5" br_lat="-33.9" zoom="299.9999%" zoom_x="-30.94%" zoom_y="-156.8%">
  <areas>
      <!-- ... -->
      <area title="ARGENTINE" mc_name="AR">
        <description><![CDATA[<?php print views_embed_view('MY_VIEW', 'VIEW_DISPLAY_ID', 'ARGUMENT'); ?>]]></description>
      </area>
      <!-- ... -->
  </areas>
</map>
```

Now, since there are many  tags that include a view, generating the XML file takes some moments which leads to long loading times for the map. For that reason I would like to cache the generated XML file somehow - taking into account that I need to add a path to it in the ammap configuration file.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do, it is to write a small module.

Here's the shortest:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_menu()
 * to define path for our xml file.
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['map.xml'] = array(
        'title' => 'Map xml',
        'page callback' => 'map_get_xml',
        'access arguments' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}

/**
 * Your custom function for xml file.
 */
function map_get_xml() {
    $cache = cache_get('your-cache-id');
    $xml = $cache->data;

    if (!$xml) {
        $xml = ... // perform your code to generate your XML

        cache_set('your-cache-id', $xml);
    }

    drupal_set_header("Content-Type:text/xml");
    print $xml;
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. It seems to be the best solution! Thanks.

Comment: Cool. So how do you control for how long something is cached, is that just by adding an expire time to the cache_set call and then check for it in the $cache->expire returned from cache_get?

Comment: The expire time is decided by your Drupal performance settings, onless you manually set an expire time in the cache_set() call.

Comment: Karel right. Also, you can use `cache_clear_all()` function to delete your cache whenever you wish (node update for example) and then generate it again.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the generated XML using cache_set and retrieve it using cache_get.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--cache.inc/function/cache_set/6

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm still a little lost, though. $data would then be the whole XML data? How do I 'tell' Drupal when to set and when to get the cache?

Comment: There's an excellent article about caching data in Drupal by Lullabot (http://www.lullabot.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-caching-data), but basically, yes, you can store the whole XML as a string and retrieve when you need it. Though, you shouldn't implement that in Drupal's index.php file, you should use Views' API to save and use cache at the right moment. (http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views)

Comment: Ok, thanks for those hints vgardner. I had already found that article, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option I found was to let the creation of the XML be initiated through cron. In that case I didn't use the cache. In a custom module:

```
<?php
function MY_MODULE_cron() {

 $content = MY_MODULE_xml();
 file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . file_directory_path() . '/MY_FILE.XML', $content);

}

function MY_MODULE_xml() {

$page_content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...';

return $page_content;

}

?>
```

Comment: Is there a better way to write to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Is this map something that is different for each user? Or is it pretty generic, and therefor pretty static?

If it's the latter, I would generate the map (on cron run most likely) and output it to a static file like sites/defaul/files/map.xml. Requests to that file will not even invoke the PHP processor, making it the fastest way to return it and have the least impact on your webserver's performance.

Comment: You're right Karel, it's a more static thing because it's just one node that doesn't get updated manually but through a view. In that case, the cron option might be better.